# Jquery - how to copy selected text from div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

lets say I have two DIVS in the page. `#news` div and `#imp` div respectively.

```
<div id="news">
Apple is facing a lawsuit for not telling users about the amount of memory required by an upgrade       its flagship operating system.
</div>

<div id="imp">
 <!-- Empty -->
</div>
```

Now my requirement is if I select only 'Apple' from the whole sentence then that selected portion gets copied and pasted into div `#imp`. And if copied, other portions then get appended.

Comment: by selected do you mean when someone highlights a word?

Comment: @jmore009 Thanks for editing. yeah exactly. highlighted word get pasted in other div #imp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#news').mouseup(function (e){
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
    $('#imp').append(text);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/xabije/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the marked text, using this library, into clipboard

https://code.google.com/p/liveclipboard-jquery/

and use jquery to insert to the div imp

Answer (score 0):

Scott Duke beat me to it but the point was to append so I changed `html` to `append` and added a space so the words don't jumble together:

```
$('#news').mouseup(function (){
   var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
   $('#imp').append(" "+ selectedText)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldkmvrqn/2/)